# Is there a 'key space' equivalent for encryption keys?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, decryption, terminology

If a **key space** is the term given to the collection of all possible decryption keys for a given cryptosystem, then what is the collection of all possible *encryption* keys called?

Comment: In a symmetric encryption system, encryption keys and decryption keys are the same thing.  Thus, the keyspace is the collection of all keys, which perform both encryption and decryption operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **key space** is the set of all possible keys that you may choose for **both** encryption and decryption keys. 
In the case of symmetric key algorithms, both encryption and decryption keys are the same. However, in asymmetric-key algorithms, with one key for encryption and another for decryption, we refer as the **key space** for both scenarios.
I hope that this explanaton will help you.